# How can I save information from a Edittext to the original file in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I'm struggling with how to save changes to my file.txt using edittext. So far my code will allow me to open up the text file, but when closing it, it will not save the changes that have been made. The text file is being opened into another activity and will save the changes when orientation changes and if it is minimized. I have tried loads of different solutions but i cannot get my head around how to store the changes that have been made.

```
public class Editor extends Activity {
private String Text;
private String Folder;
private String toast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    this.Text = extras.getString ("txt");
    this.Folder = extras.getString("s");
    this.toast = (Folder + "/" + Text);
    Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard + "/NoteTaker/" + Folder + "/" + Text);
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line);
    text.append('\n');
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv.setText(text);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_editor, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are perfoming read operation then use `InputStream`

or

if you are perfoming write operation then use `OuptputStream`

Here is [one of your solution](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523)

Comment: OMG thanks. i have been looking at this for hours trying to sort it out and it finally works

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    try{
        OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(NOTES, 0));

        out.write(editor.getText().toString());
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

You will need to alter the NOTES variable to your file_name.txt and the editor to whatever your EditText name is.

Comment: I'm getting an error on changing editor to EditText. the error is cannot make static reference to a non-static thread. i tried creating:
    EditText = edit;
 at the top and using that, but still an error.

Comment: EditText is the text box on the layout that has the information that you want to save to the file, unless you are not having the user enter their own data, in that case you wouldn't have an EditText text box. You define an EditText as such: `EditText myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_of_edittext_from_layout_xml);`